# activemq/apache-activemq-5.9.0/conf/activemq.xml (No such file or directory)?

Tags: activemq-classic

i have just installed activemq, but when i try to run the following command:

```
 ./activemq start xbean:file:workspace/activemq/apache-activemq-5.9.0/conf/activemq.xml
```

I get the following:

```
emq/apache-activemq-5.9.0/conf/activemq.xml
INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
INFO: Starting - inspect logfiles specified in logging.properties and      log4j.properties to get details
INFO: pidfile created : '/home/pi/workspace/activemq/apache-activemq-5.9.0/data/activemq-pi.pid' (pid '2576')

activemq/apache-activemq-5.9.0/bin/activemq status returns the following:

INFO: Loading '/etc/default/activemq'
INFO: Using java '/usr/bin/java'
ActiveMQ not running
```

The activemq.log says the following:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: workspace/activemq/apache-activemq-5.9.0/conf/activemq.xml./activemq (No such file or directory)
```

But the activemq.xml file is there?. I am very new to activemq and dont know where to go from here, thank you.

Comment: I think it might be fixed, when i just ran ./activemq start, it is running. i am not sure what the longer start command i tried to run does, i am following a tutorial.

Comment: The `xbean` bit is for configuration, if (for example) you want to have that separate from your installation. Perhaps what tripped you up was the use of a relative path instead of an absolute one?

Comment: Thanks, hopefully everything works ok